# Photoshop - Easier way to add date suffix, st, nd, th rd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, text

In Microsoft Word, you type

`27th` and hit a space the `th` date suffix will resize and go to top margin with a date suffix format.

In Adobe Photoshop I have to often make a new layer for adding date `th, nd, rd, st` with extra spacing and resize the text.

Can Adobe Photoshop do this? Easier way around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply a superscript styling to the suffix via the Character panel:

[image: character panel]